# AWS C#: A WebException with status ServerProtocolViolation was thrown

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

I am getting below exception even though I have selected correct region. Same code works from different machine but not from my machine.

[image: Please find attached screenshot...]

This is the exception :-

> An exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException' occurred
>   in AWSSDK.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A WebException with status
>   ServerProtocolViolation was thrown.

Here is my code:

```
   public void GetMetricList()
    {

        //var client = createCloudWatchClient();
        var client = new AmazonCloudWatchClient("#############", "##################################", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSouth1);
        ///Get list of metrics 
        var getMetricsListRequest = new ListMetricsRequest()
        {
            Namespace= "AWS/EC2"                
        };

        var metricsListResponse = client.ListMetrics(getMetricsListRequest); 
     }
```

Comment: Finally got the solution. Issue was proxy setting in my machine. What I did is simply added a line of code in my web.config file and it worked for me.
`<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>`

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the solution. Issue was proxy setting in my machine. What I did is simply added a line of code in my web.config file and it worked for me. 
    `<system.net> 
      <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" /> 
    </system.net>`